# What blog software & theme is used at

Tags: github, themes, blogs

What blog software and theme is used at **http://mmcgrana.github.com/**   ?

(e.g. Wordpress with Forest theme)

I'm confused because it's hosted at github.com but am unaware they provide their users with blog software.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for that type of question. Maybe reword the question to focus on the last piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built using Github [Pages](http://pages.github.com/) service. [Here](https://github.com/mmcgrana/mmcgrana.github.com) is the link to this repository.